# Maintain data at browser side in Angular JS or SPA based applications

Tags: angularjs

I have come from ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages backgroup, exploring Single Page application concepts and Design. In the process of that would like to understand few items such as SPA applications developed either by using AngularJS or Backbone JS , would fetch data from REST full web service such as ASP.NET web api etc. In ASP.NET the data is being placed either in cache or in ASP.NET sessions to eliminate round trips to fetch data again from database.
How is this implemented or taken care at browser? Is that by using LocalStorage , Session Storage HTML5 items. If so there is size limit for each of the browser how to manage the same.

**EDIT:** I might not have posted the question rightly, here is my intention, i wanted to completely move out to ASP.NET , i wanted to go with Angular JS in from end and ASp.NET WebAPI for REST. In this context lets assume i have retrieved list of Projects (Some Data) using Rest API during my initial load of the page. After that while navigating to a page which takes care of editing the specific project , i dont want to loose the data or information about the list of projects. Can i store list of projects in HTML5 session storage or Local storage so that when it navigate to previous page which shows the list of projects , i will pull out details from local storage or session storage instead of making again Restfull call.

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular and MVC allows you to create great SPA. You can use Angular for routing and .net in the server side.

I'll try to give you an overview of the architecture.

Angular defines the routes with the RouteProvider, in the templateUrl field instead of including an html file use an ActionResult from a MVC controller.

In the MVC controller you return the partial view that you want.

Your question was about how to handle data and here's how I do it

Create an API Rest that access to your db and make ajax requests from the Angular controllers. With this you can get, post, edit or delete data from the server. Recommended for db access.

If you are more interested in storing data in .net session variables you have two options:

1. You can handle session variables in the MVC controller called from Angular, creating or editing them and afterwards just use them in the view.
2. Or you can create an http post method in an MVC controller and send a json from the angular controller when a button is clicked for example. The data is sent to the server and using .net you can store that data, handle your session variables and even return a json to angular with whatever information you want to send back to the client.

I hope this can give you a general view of how everything works together.

Comment: Yes, if you want to storage data in the client take a look at angular services as optimus said.

Answer (score 0):

Look at angular services/factory, to start with look this [link](http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/09/angularjs-service-vs-factory-with-example/).
you can also use localstorage in browser, but think about what will happen if the data changes frequently.